# What is the recommended method for removing Polymer elements from the page/registry?

Tags: javascript, polymer

We'd like to be able to replace element definitions at run-time. No need to assume that elements in the DOM will be magically updated. We'd just like to be able to recycle the element name.

What is the recommended method for removing Polymer elements from the page/registry entirely?

e.g. Remove  for  version 1, add  for  version 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Once a custom element name is registered on the page, it can't be re-registered. Try running `var XFoo = document.registerElement('x-foo');` twice in the console in Chrome.

In a future version of the Custom Elements spec there may be an element registry to manage. But that's a ways off.

Comment: Is there a way to *remove* them?

Comment: No. Browser vendors required the spec to say that element registrations were immutable, because the alternative would involve potentially doing bad things with lots of elements already existing and interacting with the DOM.